# Upload hangs on Windows 10 and Atheros AR8152 NIC

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter, telegram-messenger

I have a strange problem with my laptop running Windows 10. When I try to upload some file (from Telegram messenger, from the browser on Imgur/VK/whatever) it hangs and doesn't pass. Process starts, the upload gauge is moving but then it hangs up and the transfer freezes. Re-trying for a few times helps for one time.

This problem appears only with the Ethernet adapter, Atheros AR8152. The cable is OK (I have tested it with other computer and tester), network is also OK (tested with other different devices). It also works perfectly when I use Wi-Fi stick instead of the wired network adapter, so it seems that there is some problem with it or its driver. I also suspect that this problem appeared after Windows has updated itself to 1151 version.

I tried to ping some servers for a long time and it is quite stable. I'm also posting this question using this adapter, so, it seems that this problem appears only with big chunks of data.

**How to fix this problem?** Also, how to stress-test my NIC? How to determine the condition when this problem appears?

Things I tried are these:

- [All steps from Microsoft's guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-network-connection-issues)
- Reinstalling drivers and testing different versions from *atheros.cz* (there were no drivers for Windows 10 so I tried ones for Windows 8)
- Force device removal and rolling back to standard Windows' driver

None of these helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody answered me, but I fixed the upload problem experimentally and I want to share my experience with those who's stuck with this problem too.

For the first you need to roll back your NIC driver to version **2.1.0.16** and which is provided by **Microsoft**, e.g. built-in driver. To do this, use Device Manager: press <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, type `devmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then choose your NIC: expand `Network Adapters` part and seek for something containing `Atheros AR8152`. Double-click on the NIC item and go to `Driver` tab. In this tab press the `Roll Back Driver` button. Agree with the caution dialog. After that make sure that you have Microsoft's driver. Do not close properties window.

The second step is editing driver's settings to make it work properly. Go to `Advanced` tab and edit the settings in the list at left according to these values:

- Large Send Offload (IPv4) = **Disabled**
- Large Send Offload v2 (IPv4) = **Disabled**
- Max IRQ per second = **9000** (experimentally found)
- Transmit Buffers = **1024**

After that hit the `OK` button. Connection will be interrupted and then restored. After that I finally have no problems with file uploading.